# Publish local Maven project to local Gradle repository

Tags: java, maven, gradle, repository, maven-publish

I have a Java Maven project.

Is it somehow possible to publish my Maven project with Maven into my local Gradle repository?

Is there maybe some plugin for this?

Comment: Are you talking about the Gradle cache? You should not access the cache manually. Why don't you want to use the local Maven repository?

Comment: @LukasKörfer I thought there was the equivalent of a local Maven repository for Gradle too. Since this doesn't exist, my question probably doesn't make sense.

Comment: Gradle only has an internal cache. But you can easily access the local Maven repository both as a package source and as a publishing target.

Comment: With `mvn install`, you can install the jar in your local Maven folder- that is, in the [userdir]/.m2 folder . You can then edit the Gradle build to retrieve dependencies from the local Maven folder, so that your build will use the jar you just installed. (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/repository_types.html#sub:maven_local)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was mentioned in the comments, Gradle does not have a repository.